# FetchedResultsController and UITableView in multiple views

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Summary: I have two different views which use tables to show results from a fetched results controller. These tables **may contain the same data**. I get errors when moving the rows in one table after the other table has been loaded. (Obvious I suppose!)

To simplify, imagine an entity consisting of countries, and another entity grouping these countries together into sets of countries. We have an "editSet" view which allows you to name the set, add or delete countries in the set, as well as reorder them, all using the standard UI. We then have a "viewSet" view that shows you these countries and some value associated with them (eg. exchange rate or whatever).

Now, in the edit view, when we reorder and moveRowAtIndexPath is invoked, I set a BOOL which stops any further UI changes until the coredata is updated (each record has a displayOrder integer which I update before doing another performSearch). This all works perfectly if you only have instantiated the "editSet" view.

Where things goes wrong is if you load "viewSet" then load "editSet" with the same set and move the rows. The BOOL we set in editSet doesn't get passed along to viewSet (which is also "watching" the coredata) and gets upset when the coredata is changed programmatically. This generates:

```
Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of
NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:
.  *** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]:
index 0 beyond bounds for empty array with userInfo (null)
```

And all hell breaks lose.

On the other hand, if I load/appear "viewSet" with A DIFFERENT SET to the one I am editing, no problems.

So, what I need to do is EITHER "disconnect" the FRC and the table when leaving viewSet (perhaps do a search on nothing and reload the table?) OR pass a BOOL to the viewSetController when saving the moved rows in coredata in editSet to mimc what I do locally in that viewcontroller (not quite sure how to do this but doable I guess).

I am sure I am not the first to come across this problem, so wondering, what's the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Use another managed object context for your "edits" and then merge them back in when you go back to your "viewSet". Take a look in the Apple sample code project 'CoreDataBooks' to see how you can use two contexts to perform disjoint edits.

Comment: I ended up doing a search deliberately designed to produce zero results and updating the table on viewWillDisappear. This solved it, but with a minor performance hit. I've recently realized an alternative would be to use userDefaults as a kinda of "global" to store the ObjectID of the set being edited, and get the viewSet controller to check this. I havent implemented this but its another idea.